# FourSquare API is giving lots of result but not the result I expect

Tags: api, foursquare

I am using FourSquare api for searching a particular business

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/search?name=Spa Gregories&oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

it is giving lots of result but not the result i expect. that is 
Spa Gregories
2710 Via De La Valle, Ste B-270
San Diego, California 92014
when i use https://foursquare.com/search?q=Spa+Gregories&near=san+diago then i got the exact result. So is their any way to find the business according the location. I have only name and city location to use for Search. I have also checked for the venues option but it asks for longitude and latitude.
thnks

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're hitting the **user search** endpoint instead of the **venue search**.

Looks like this is the one you want:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html